# Do coproducts injections of Heyting algebras have left and right adjoints?

Tags: lo.logic, boolean-algebras, modal-logic, stone-duality

Given two Heyting algebras $A$ and $B$, let $A+B$ be their coproduct in the category of Heyting algebras. Is it true that the inclusion $A → A+B$ always has a left and a right adjoint ? (Actually, I want to know if the dual map of Esakia spaces is always open, which is stronger.)

**Context:** In 1992, Pitts showed uniform interpolation for intuitionistic logic. It is deduced in the same paper that if $A$ is any Heyting algebra and if $B$ is finitely presented, then the canonical inclusion $A→A+B$ has a left and a right adjoint. Actually, the dual map between Esakia spaces is even open, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01630). Hence I wonder if any inclusion of this form, with $B$ an arbitrary Heyting algebra, has a left and a right adjoint.

Here is what I can show about the Heyting algebras $B$ satisfying this property (for all $A$):

1. They include all the free Heyting algebras over a distributive lattice. (i.e., the Heyting algebras presented by an arbitrary number of variables and by equations not using the implication)
2. They are closed under sub-Heyting algebras and arbitrary products.
3. They include all the finite Heyting algebras and all the linear Heyting algebras (satisfying $(a→b) ∨ (b→a) = ⊤$).

In particular, this class includes all the Boolean algebras, all the [profinite Heyting algebras](https://www.cs.le.ac.uk/people/nb118/Publications/Bezh-Bezh-final.pdf)...

Comment: I am not familiar with the *category* of Heyting algebras, but it would be useful to consider the same statements in the category of *frames*, or its opposite category of *locales*. In that setting, the right adjoint says (most of) that $B$ is *compact* and the left that it is *overt*. Overt locales were previously called *open*, since the projections are open maps. That these adjoints exist for your examples may simply be picking up these properties.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Thanks! However, there is something important to take note of when we think in dual terms (Esakia spaces, locales...). In the category of locales, every projection map is open (in classical mathematics); but in the category of Esakia spaces, products are computed in a non-obvious way (the points of a product can be presented as certain Kripke structures modulo bisimilarity), and this is what makes the question of determining if projection maps are open non-obvious.

Comment: I hadn't heard of Esakia spaces, so please add a link to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esakia_space) or some other explanation. In 1974 not many people were being careful about excluded middle, so I suggest re-working the duality proof. Then try to adapt the theory of proper and open maps of locales (or of compact and overt locales as objects). Beware of the difference between frame and Heyting algebra homomorphisms! Classical logic will just be an obstacle to exploiting this analogy.

Comment: If you put your real name, location and email address on your MathOverflow profile, other users will be able to point you to relevant experts nearby.